# Solving Linear Congruences for Affine Cipher.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

### Question

Find all pairs of integers keys $\left(a,b \right)$ for **afﬁne ciphers** for which the encryption function
$$c\equiv\left( ap + b \right) \pmod{26} $$
is the same as the corresponding decryption function.

### My Approach

$$c\equiv\left( ap + b \right)\pmod {26}$$

Decryption function 
$$p\equiv\left( c- b \right) \times a^{-1}\pmod{26}$$

equalizing both equation, we have

$$\left( ap + b \right)\pmod{26}\equiv\left( c- b \right) \times a^{-1}\pmod{26}$$

No idea what to do next. Please help me out ! thanks

Comment: You appear to have a misconception about functions. $a p + b$ is a function of $p$, while $(c - b) a^{-1}$ is a function of $c$, so equating them makes little sense. Write them in the same variable, say $a x + b \equiv (x - b) a^{-1} \pmod{26}$ and you'll get the beginning of my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I am writing congruences as identities, for simplicity of notation.

**Hint 1**

You want to find $a, b$  such that modulo $26$ the identity $$p = a (a p + b) + b = a^{2} p + a b + b,$$ that is $$(a^{2} - 1) p + (a + 1) b = 0,$$ holds for all $p$.

**Hint 2**

> Setting $p = 0$ we obtain $(a + 1) b = 0$.

**Hint 3**

> Setting $p = 1$ we obtain $a^{2} = 1$ which yields $a = \pm 1$.

**Hint 4**

> If $a = -1$ we are fine for all $b$.

**Hint 5**

> If $a = 1$, then $2 b = 0$, so $b = 0, 13$.

Comment: @:Andreas  sir i am okk with $a* \left(ap+b\right) =c-b\,\, \Rightarrow a* \left(ap+b\right)+b=c $ but unable to get how $a* \left(ap+b\right)+b=p$???

Comment: Just re-read your own question!

Comment: Sr i am not getting ! even if i am putting the value  of $c=ap+b$then my equation reduces to $a* \left( ap+b\right)=ap$ .please help me out !

Comment: See my comment to your question.

Comment: @laura If the encryption function is $E(p)$, then you want the encryption of the encryption, i.e. $E(E(p))$,  to be $p$ again **for all* $p \in \mathbb{Z}_{26}$, hence the equation.

Comment: How is it that you’re able to vary p between 1 and 0? (Hints 2 and 3)

Comment: @mehsheenman the second displayed identity has to hold for all $p$, so one can certainly specialise $p = 0, 1$.